# conjugation of Sylow group is generated by conjugation from the including normal group

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group. Let $K\triangleleft G$ and $P$ some $p$-Sylow subgroup of $K$.

**Prove** that for all $g\in G$, there exist $k\in K$ such that $gPg^{-1}=kPk^{-1}$.

**Deduce** that $G=K\cdot N_G(P)$.

For the second part we get that for all $g\in G$ there is some $k\in K$ such that $k^{-1}g\in N_G(P)$ from the "prove" part, so it is obvious that $G=K\cdot N_G(P)$.

Comment: Do you happen to know Sylow's theorems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: apply Sylow theory in $K$. $G$ acts on $K$ by conjugation. The theorem you want to prove is called the Frattini Argument.